# VS 2015: How to "remember" TFS path?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-studio-2015

In VS 2010 the Source Control Explorer would simply remember your last TFS tree selection and jump the very same branch and sub-folder again.

VS 2015 always starts at the very root node and you have to annoyingly navigate to your work branch every time.

Is there a way to make it remember the path like 2010 did?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forget it, I just should have a taken a proper look at the VS TFS settings in the options...

"Open Source Control Explorer to the most recent folder"

Comment: This exact same thing just happened to me in VS 2017.  Not always a bad thing to have this step documented.